# Sparse categorical cross entropy not working as expected

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, time-series, classification

I am working on MIMIC 3 data set to classify patients. I have 7000 classes and the range of values of class is upto 50000, labels are integers. So I used sparse categorical entropy loss so that I dont have to worry about high range of labels. But I my model gives a nan loss on the labels greater than 7000.

```
n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = 50, 59, 7000
batch_size=32
model = Sequential()
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(32, input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
```

I am normalizing the data by

```
def normalize(df):

  header=df.columns
  subid_col=df['SUBJECT_ID']
  label_col=df['label']
  df = df.replace(0, np.NaN)
  df=pd.DataFrame(df).fillna(method="ffill")
  df=pd.DataFrame(df).fillna(df.mean())
  df=pd.DataFrame(df).fillna(-99)
  x = df.values
  header=df.columns

  min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (1,2))
  x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
  df = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
  df=pd.DataFrame(df).fillna(-1)

  df.columns=header

  df['SUBJECT_ID']=subid_col
  df['label']=label_col
  df.drop(df.columns[0], axis = 1, inplace = True)

  return df
```

I am doing a time series classification.

Comment: What's the point of using 3 different `fillna` methods sequentially one after the other?

Comment: The first one fills the Nan below data (in a column) the second one fills the remaining nans above data in columns. and the 3rd will fill the columns of only nans

Answer (score 0):

Since your final layer is of length `n_outputs=7000`,  [`sparse_categorical_crossentropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/sparse_categorical_crossentropy) expects labels in index notation in the range `[0, 7000]`. You thus need to map your labels before training i.e:

```py
from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(label_col)

df['label'] = le.transform(label_col)
```

To retrieve the 'true' labels from the encoding you can use `le.inverse_transform(label_col)`.

---

Alternatively you could just change your `n_outputs = 50000`, but this would arguably be inefficient if you are only training on / expecting to see a subset of 7000 of these, since you are unnecessarily adding parameters which would ideally be learned as `0`, since you have no data with these labels.

Comment: [0,7000] would have 7001 labels